# How to execute my custom action when right-clicking on a TMemo control?

Tags: delphi, contextmenu, delphi-10.4-sydney, tmemo

In a Delphi 10.4.2 32-bit VCL Application, I need to do different actions when the user (left- or right-)clicks on a `TMemo` control (which is in `ReadOnly` mode):

```
procedure TForm1.Memo1MouseDown(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton; Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
begin
  if Button = mbLeft then
    DoAction1
  else if Button = mbRight then
    DoAction2;
end;
```

`DoAction2` consists of invoking a specific dialog.

However, when I right-click on the Memo control, the native context menu of the `TMemo` control shows up, and `DoAction2` is not executed:

[image]

I have tried to deactivate the right-click context menu of the Memo control with this code:

```
Memo1.OnContextPopup := nil;
```

But it does not work: The context menu still shows up when right-clicking the Memo control.

So how can I deactivate the native context menu and execute my action when right-clicking on the Memo control?

Comment: Have you considered moving your left-click action to the `OnClick` event, and your right-click action to the `OnContextPopup` event?

Comment: @RemyLebeau: Just remember that you can invoke the context menu by other means than right-clicking.

Comment: @RemyLebeau You are right: that would have been another possibility. But then I would have never discovered the type ambiguity (see below).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is easy.

Your code `Memo1.OnContextPopup := nil;` has no effect because the `Memo1.OnContextPopup` property already is `nil`, as you can see in the **Object Inspector**; that is, by default you have no custom handler.

What you need to do is to *add* such a custom handler and set the `Handled` `var` property to `True`. At design time, use the **Object Inspector** to create an `OnContextPopup` handler for your memo, with the following code:

```pascal
procedure TForm1.Memo1ContextPopup(Sender: TObject; MousePos: TPoint;
  var Handled: Boolean);
begin
  Handled := True;
end;
```

Now the default context menu is suppressed and you can try, for example,

```pascal
procedure TForm1.Memo1MouseDown(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton;
  Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
begin
  if Button = mbLeft then
    Winapi.Windows.Beep(300, 250)
  else if Button = mbRight then
    Winapi.Windows.Beep(300, 1000);
end;
```

Comment: The `OnMouseDown` event-handler is executed, but neither `if Button = mbLeft` nor `if Button = mbRight then` conditions are met.

Comment: @user1580348: I doubt that. What *is* the value of `Button`?

Comment: Well, `TMouseButton` only has 3 values defined, so if it is not `mbLeft` or `mbRight` then it must be `mbMiddle`.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: If something has gone wrong, it can also be `TMouseButton(152)` or anything... But I suspect there is a test-case error here; the code above works in a new VCL project.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand all of the places in the VCL's code that trigger the `OnMouse...` events are hard-coding the `Button` parameter, so it should never be something other than then 3 values mentioned.

Comment: I have been the victim of a TYPE AMBIGUITY: I had to rename the type `TMouseButton` to `Vcl.Controls.TMouseButton`, and the type `mbRight` to `Vcl.Controls.mbRight`. Now it works.